# Truecaller Flutter SDK Limit Exceeded

Tags: flutter

I am integrating the [official truecaller SDK](https://github.com/truecaller/flutter-sdk) for flutter. While integrating it, I get phone number limit exceed after 2-3 tires. Further, if I use some other number, after another 2-3 tries, I get request id limit exceeded. Any work around for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a throttling limit on the number of fresh verification attempts allowed via Truecaller SDK for a per device + phone number combination. This is mostly done in order to prevent request abuse and keeping in mind the security considerations. The limit is pretty generous and won't impact your real users when your app is in production. In case you faced throttling limit on any of your numbers, the limit gets auto reset within 24 hours, and you can try again post that.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the answer! I wanted to ask, it there a development environment available for developers to test it out? I believe this would really help developers to quicky integrate and test the SDK right away!

Comment: @DaniyalAbbasi This should answer your doubt - https://github.com/truecaller/flutter-sdk/issues/10